# How to scroll in any direction with evince PDF viewer using mouse dragging

Tags: touchpad, pdf, evince, usability

When viewing large PDFs with small print where one has to zoom in to be able to read even on fullscreen, it would be nice to be able to move the 'paper' with the drag of the mouse (hand cursor type).

Is there also a solution for dragging left--right using the touchpad?

Comment: right-click, `Autoscroll`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can drag using middle mouse button in evince to scroll the document.

[image: middle mouse button]

Comment: Chrome's PDF viewer supports the [middle mouse button scrolling](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/what-should-the-middle-mouse-button-mean.html) as discussed in the article that picture is from.

Comment: thanks. any hint on how to achieve it without middle mouse button, e.g. on a touchpad?

Comment: @type: You can also Edit->Toolbar and add the Autoscroll button.

Comment: interesting, but actually i'm more concerned about left--right scrolling ...

Comment: @type Either press the middle button or *both* left and right button to scroll.

Comment: ah, both buttons emulate middle one in case of not being present -- any chance of setting evince to drag like that by default, ie without middle/both touchpad buttons being pressed (maybe via gconf)? cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using other PDF readers, qpdfview can scroll with left mouse button.

`sudo apt-get install qpdfview qpdfview-ps-plugin`

(qpdfview-ps-plugin is optional but without it you will get "Cannot load PS plugin!" error dialog every time you open the settings screen)

Answer (score 0):

Vertical scrolling: scroll wheel.
Horizontal scroll:  + scroll wheel.
Arbitrary drag: press middle button (scroll wheel) and move around.

With touch pad, two fingers up/down and left-right for scrolling. Doesn't work well on my machine, too sensitive.